# Ajax form submission using button

Tags: html, ajax, forms, post

Seems there are a ton of answers to nearly identical questions, but I can't seem to solve this.  Please forgive me if you've seen this a thousand times:

I have a form I need to submit using ajax, but I can't get it to do it properly.  It needs to submt, and not refresh (as you'd expect), but it doesn't seem to matter what I do, all I can get it to do is append the POST to the current URL of the page.  I've stripped the form down to the bare minimum, and am still getting this result, so I must be doing something really wrong.  Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form class="form horizontal" id="logForm">
            <fieldset>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <div style="float: left">
                        <label for="from">Start Date: </label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" id="from" name="from" />
                        </div>
                        <label for="to">End Date:</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" id="to" name="to" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>

            <div class="form-actions">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="subButton" style="float: left">Search!</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <script>
            $("#logForm").submit(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'logQuery.php',
                    type: 'get',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: $('form#logForm').serialize(),
                    success: function(html) {
                    alert('worked good');
                    return false;
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your script add ready and return false on proper line. You `return false` when asynchronus operation is done which may be after the function returns. That is why you don't prevent the standard behaviour of submit event.

**Return should be inside `submit()` function.**

**Hint:**

You don't need to use `form#logForm` because there is only one element with id=logForm (it should be at least) `#logForm` is enough.

Also always use document.ready when you binding events to elements. This will make you sure that all elements on site are loaded so you can bind events to them.

You can use also `preventDefault()` but `return false` is good too.

```
 $(function (){
       $("#logForm").submit(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'logQuery.php',
                type: 'get',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: $('form#logForm').serialize(),
                success: function(html) {
                alert('worked good');
                }
            });
           return false;
        });

 });
```

Comment: Thanks so much; that makes all kinds of sense.  Really appreciate it.